# Using union/struct member as gcc inline asm argument

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly

I have several struct/unions, for example:

```c
union
{
    uint8_t X;
    struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))
    {
    uint8_t A  : 1;
    uint8_t B  : 1;
    uint8_t C  : 1;
    uint8_t D  : 1;
    uint8_t E  : 1;
    uint8_t F  : 1;
    uint8_t G  : 1;
    uint8_t H  : 1;
    };
}DATA;
```

I need to access their elements in in-line assembly, for example:

```c
asm volatile
(
"\
    mov %1, %%eax       \t\n\
    inc %%eax           \t\n\
    mov $0, %0      \t\n\
"
:"=d"(u->X)
:"d"(temp)      
);
```

Application segfaults at the last line.

```c
mov    (%rdx),%eax                     
inc    %eax                        
mov    $0x0,%dl                        
mov    %dl,0x1(%rax)
```

I tried to create a mirror pointer and access struct via it but it doesn't had an effect, just no segfault. So I use temp variable. Is it possible at all or I try to do a weird things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline assembly must not alter registers which are not listed as outputs or in the clobber list.

In your example the compiler has chosen to store `u` in RAX, which is altered by your code. EAX is the lower half of RAX.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly right. I fixed the issue by adding eax to the clobber part of asm template

Comment: Moving a named register to the clobber list is "almost never" the correct fix (there are other ways - either to use in/out operands, `"+d"(u->X)`, or to use _aliases_ / _early clobbers_, `"=&d"(u->X) : "0"(temp)`). The result of your code, no matter _how_ structured, is functionally equivalent to `u->X = 0;` - what is it you're trying to do there ?